# Php composer Ambiguous class resolution issue

Tags: php, composer-php

I have this message when I run composer install

Warning: Ambiguous class resolution

means 2 files have same classname

1. a.deprecated.php
2. a.php

which is clear enough and I am going to ask the third party to remove one of the file as same namespace cannot have a same classname in 2 different files.

but the issue is composer install works in my local because composer chooses the a.php which has all the functions but it doesn't work on server because 
there the first file is a.deprecated.php

On my local the composer warning is

Ambiguous class resolution,"NAME_SPACE\Util\Somelib\" was found in both "/vendor/a.php" and "/vendor/a.deprecated.php" the first will be used.

and on sever it's

Ambiguous class resolution,"NAME_SPACE\Util\Somelib\" was found in both "/vendor/a.deprecated.php" and "/vendor/a.php" the first will be used.

and becuase a.php is what I need it's all good in local but on server it doesn't work :( because a.deprecated.php doesn't contains all the functions.

I just want to understand why on sever a.deprecated.php is the first file?

also because it's a third party plugin, I will ask them to delete the a.deprecated.php but is there any solution so that I can exclude this file?

Comment: Are you running same composer version on both environments?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller using Dockerfile 


`RUN set -ex &&\
 curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer &&\
 COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress --no-suggest`

Comment: composer version is same as as the composer is installed using above command but and I am using php:5.6.35-apache-jessie image, does anyone have any idea, what could cause this ?